# Python: repeating function that replaces x with a number (1 ~ 3) that increases with each pass

Tags: python

How would i make this piece of code work so that it will replace x with a number that changes each time the function passes?

```
P1 = 1
P2 = 2
P3 = 3

for x in range(1,3):
  global P(x)
  print (P(x))
  x += 1
```

I want it to print the value of P1, then P2, then P3. (Printing those is not my actual goal its just like a test script rather than pasting my 400 line script in.)

Thanks

Comment: don't do this. make a list out of all your P variables. call it, i don't know, `p_variables` i guess. `p_variables = [P1, P2, P3]` . Iterate through this list.

Comment: Yes but if i do that I can't actually set and change the variables throughout the rest of the script. What i need to do i somehow run a snippet of code(in this instance "print Px", but in actuality its a script thats 13 lines long but its repeated 9 times with a slight variation, i want to just have it written 1 time so its not so ugly looking.)

Comment: You're solving an XY problem. Your code should never have been written in such a way that *this* is the answer.

Comment: Ok, I have the Git repo here https://github.com/AmethystCash/aaa/blob/master/B
if you look at lines 91 to 269 you can see its essentially the same thing 9 times. How do I make it be only 1 of those 9 repetitions of the same code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, following with print your variables dynamically using your defined naming scheme:

```
P1 = 1
P2 = 2
P3 = 3

for x in range(1,4):
  print(eval("P"+str(x)))
  eval("P"+str(x)) == P1
  eval("P"+str(x)) == P2
  eval("P"+str(x)) == P3
```

Output:

```
1
True
False
False
2
False
True
False
3
False
False
True
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes it is thank you, for each instance where i want to replace "x" do i just paste "(eval("P"+str(x)))" ? and will that work if i want to change the value of the P variable?

Comment: Glad you got what you need. Please accept this as answer, if this answers your question.

Comment: Yes, just testing the code. I seem to be having an error where its meant to go if x = P1,then continue to if x = P2 ect but its not doing that. Cn you think of a reason it might not do that?

Comment: if eval("P"+str(x)) == P1, for comparison. I have added this in my answer as well.

Comment: I figured out what was actually wrong, I have made an error in my previous comment. I need this snippet to be updated
`if Turn == "X":`
      ` P1 = "X"`
        `Turn = "O" `

Comment: You're welcome. You can close your question now. Enjoy your stay on Stack Overflow.